# Why do standalone object literals result in SyntaxError in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Using the JavaScript console on Chrome:

```
> [1, 2]
[1, 2]
> {a: 1, b: 2}
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
> {a: 1}
1
```

Why are standalone array literals allowed, but not standalone object literals...and what's happening with the third statement here?

(Similar results on Firefox, but the node.js CLI will happily understand both of the last two statements as object literals.)